# Can't install a package with YUM

Tags: installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I've installed YUM 2.0.7. When I try `yum install kernel-headers` for example I get the following error:

[image]

What should I do for a fix?

P.S. I've installed version 2.0.7 of YUM because I'm required to use Redhat 9 for my operating systems course.

Comment: Did you try to google your error? I have found [this](http://surachartopun.com/2013/01/yum-yum-errno-4-ioerror.html). Try

Comment: Really?  RH9?   Is the class titled 'what computers were like in 2001'?   I would assume most of the repos are not going to work considering how old of a release you are using.    What school is this ?

Comment: I was wrong, RH9 was released in 2003, not 2001.   Linux has come such a long way since RH9 (which was the first Linux distro I used back when I was in college).  Many nights were spent ripping my hair out with that distro.   Somehow I kept with it and have a very good understanding of Linux today, but the thought of having to go back and use RH9 makes me cringe.

Comment: @Richie086 That's what happens when your instructors doesn't update their knowledge according to the timeline they're in by being careless when it comes to education. Trust me, I feel really bad about it as well but I'm stuck unfortunately.

Comment: @khajvah I Googled many times with no luck. Thanks for giving me a direction.